# What is the difference between a serial code and using the keyword critical while parallelizing a code in openmp?

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

If I have just one for loop to parallelize and if I use #pragma omp critical while parallelizing, will that make it equivalent to a serial code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The `critical` directive specifies that the code it covers is executed by one thread at a time, but it will (eventually) be executed by all threads that encounter it.

The `single` directive specifies that the code it covers will only be executed by one thread but even that isn't exactly the same as compiling the code without OpenMP.  OpenMP imposes some restrictions on what programming constructs can be used inside parallel regions (*eg* no jumping out of them).  Furthermore, at run-time you are likely to incur an overhead for firing up OpenMP even if you don't actually run any code in parallel.